# What is the exact number of jataka tales?

Tags: the-buddha, literature, birth-stories

What is the exact number of original jataka tales? If we look around we see Jataka tales, panchatantra, Esop's fables and many others are all mixed up. Where can I read original Jataka tales online?

Answer (score 6):

### What is the exact number of jātaka tales?

The [*Khuddaka Nikāya*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khuddaka_Nikaya) counts 547 [*Jātaka* Tales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jataka_tales).

---

### Where can I read original Jātaka tales online?

At [Sacred Texts](http://www.sacred-texts.com/bud/index.htm#jataka) there are 6 translated volumes that contain all of them.